# WP database error Unknown column ‘wp_’ in ‘field list’ for query SELECT wp_

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**Please do not close this question, it's not a duplicate and the suggested link explaining how to use quotes on MySQL does nothing for me since this problem is inside a WP script. Thanks**

I’m trying to install WP 5.4.1 on a **clean** Windows 2019 Server virtual machine.

I didn’t use `Microsoft Web Platform Installer` since it download old versions of WP / MySQL and PHP, so I’m trying to install from scratch.

Here are the steps I’ve taken:

- Downloaded and Installed latest `PHP 7.4.5`, non thread safe version
  and installed it
- renamed `php.ini-production` to `php.ini`
- Edited php.ini to:

  - upload_max_filesize = 64M
  - post_max_size = 64M
  - max_execution_time = 300
  - extesion=mysqli (removed the semicolon here since PHP needs this driver to connect to MySQL8)
- In IIS I created the *.php mapping and added default.php and index.php
- Created the dummy `phpinfo.php` file and tested on IIS, **all working correctly and phpinfo() shows data**
- Downloaded `MySQL 8.0.20` and installed with the following options:

  - Server only
  - Standalone
  - Server computer
  - For the authentication method I choose ‘Use Stron password encryption’ as suggested by the PHP installer
- added MySQL BIN folder to `path` environment variable
- opened `%PROGRAMDATA%\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini` and disabled sha2 and enable native_password:

  - ;default_authentication_plugin=caching_sha2_password
  - default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
- created a new database for WP, called `wp1` (in MySQL 8, the ‘one liner’ to create the user and grant access at the same time doesn’t work, so we need to do it in 2 lines)

```
  mysql -u root -p
  create database wp1;
  CREATE USER ‘wp1’@’%’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘password’;
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wp1.* TO ‘wp1’@’%’;
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
  EXIT
```

- created the folder `C:\intepub\wwroot\wp1` and give full access to `IUSR` and `Users` windows groups so WP can write the config files
- In IIS, right click on the `Default Web Site` and click on `Add Application` pointing to the new `wp1` folder
- navigate to `localhost/wp1` to start WP installation

So after selecting the language and entering the DB info, I get this error

`WordPress database error Unknown column ‘wp_’ in ‘field list’ for query SELECT wp_`

After hours fighting with this, here’s what I found:

- the error came from the DB, not WP.
- tried with both `wp1` and `root` users during the installation
- tried with both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` during the installation
- the error generates in setup-config.php file, line 315 $wpdb->query("SELECT $prefix")
- seems the problem is that what arrives at MySQL is the string select wp_ insted of select 'wp_' (note the missing quotes)
- If I go to MySQL and execute select wp_ I get the exact same error

So the issue seems to be related to how MySQL 8.0 is handling quotes in the query it receives from WP installer…

I restored a snapshot just before installing MySQL 8.0.20 and this time, instead of 
`Use Strong Password Encryption for Authentication`
I selected
`Use Legacy Authentication Method (Retain MySQL 5.x Compatibility)` but the error is still the same

Before answering, please consider:

- I’m looking to solve the issue, not to start a discussion whatever I should use MySQL 5.x instead of MySQL 8.x
- Yes, the connection to the database is Ok, that’s not the problem, please read all the my post
- Yes, wp-config is being written with the correct values

Even tough I saw many messages with this same error on the WP forum, they normally have no answer, or the answer don’t make any sense (like asking to OP to check the DB credentials and write access to the WP folder), [still I posted on the WP forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/database-error-unknowon-column-wp_-in-field-list-for-query-select-wp_/#post-12797802), but I no answer yet.

Sorry for my poor formatting!

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Oddly, I think it's doing what it's supposed to do. The code in question is `$errors = $wpdb->hide_errors();
                $wpdb->query( "SELECT $prefix" );
                $wpdb->show_errors( $errors );
                if ( ! $wpdb->last_error ) {
                       ( // MySQL was able to parse the prefix as a value, which we don't want. Bail.)
                        wp_die( __( '<strong>Error</strong>: "Table Prefix" is invalid.' ) );
                }`  So that line is supposed fail, but it should continue on

Comment: @aynber Also I don't get the `table prefix is invalid` text, but if I put an invalid prefix I do get the `table prefix is invalid` message. So you are right, somehow WP is halting the script execution after the error inside MySQL

Comment: @anyber is there some kind of `halt on error` or `stop on error` that needs to be configured in PHP or MySQL and I missed that step?

Comment: You might want to check your PHP error settings in php.ini. I couldn't tell you right now what it should be. The `hide_errors()`/`show_errors()` is supposed to suppress that particular error, so maybe for some reason `hide_errors` is not setting show_errors to false. (looking in wp-includes/wp-db.php for the exact code)

Comment: @aynber php.ini has `display_errors = Off`

Comment: In my case it was caused by an incompatible version from XAMPP (8.x) and WordPress (5.8.2)
Using a beta version from WordPress (5.9.x) solved my issue. See also https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/54579#comment:2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found the issue...

**TLDR;** edit your `php.ini` and make sure you have both:

`display_errors = On`

`error_log = php_errors.log`

Setting **error_log** solves the issue... I guess that when **error_log** has no value (default configuration), PHP decides to send the error back to the calling program, resulting in the error message `column 'wp_' in 'field list'` during the WP installation.

[More details here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42362)

Answer (score 3):

I just deleted lines 317 to 322 in `wp-admin\setup-config.php` re-ran the setup and it all worked fine.

Might not be the right solution but the only thing that worked for me.

This was for WP 5.5.3, previous versions I had no issues downloading and installing

Answer (score 3):

**This error is possible if WordPress version doesn't support server's PHP version.**

In my case I recently installed the latest XAMPP with PHP 8.1.1 and had to downgrade PHP to 8.0.14 in order for WordPress 5.8.2/5.8.3 to be installed and work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted lines 317 to 322 in wp-admin\setup-config.php re-ran the setup and it all worked fine.

Might not be the right solution but the only thing that worked for me.

This was for WP 5.5.3, previous versions I had no issues downloading and installing

Same for me on version 5.6.2 when trying to install a second site using the same database so needed new table prefix

Comment: Hello :),This answer has already been answered. If you have nothing to add to the original answer please consider removing this.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions is worked for my case. Because I have already installed Mysql workbench on my windows machine. I stopped the already running mysql server, I have followed the below mentioned steps.

Open command prompt, then navigate to the following path

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\
```

Then executed the following command

```
mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

After that I restarted the apache and mysql on xampp server it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, for me the problem was in **php folder (exactly "php.ini" file)**, so to get the standard settings I just installed windows server 2019 in VMWare then installed "php 7.4" using web platform, then I copied the PHP folder from VMWare "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.4" to my PC (windows10), then I download "wordpress5.8.2", and "mysql8.0.1", after installing mysql and creating DB for wordpress(just create DB) and setup the IIS in my windows10, I ran localhost and every thing working good and wordpress installed without any errors.

So try to get the php.ini that installed with web platform and overwrite it on your php folder and run, if it does not work try to copy the whole php folder and try again, I tried this with php 8.0 but have many errors.